# I get undefined from state

Tags: reactjs, state

I have problem, in the code below I'm trying to console.log only name of the playLists from state with `console.log(this.state.playLists.name);` I get undefined.

```
getPlaylist() {
    spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists().then((response) => {
      if (response.items) {
        const items = response.items;
        console.log(items);
        const playListsId = items.map((obj) => {
          const playList = {
            name: obj.name,
            id: obj.id,
          };
          return playList;
        });
        console.log(playListsId);

        this.setState({
          playLists: playListsId,
        });
      }
      console.log(this.state.playLists.name);
    });
  }
```

Comment: `playListsId` is an array, you should log console.log(this.state.playLists[0].name);

Comment: Just wait, I would try this:
```javascript
async function getPlaylist(){
const userPlaylist = await spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists()
console.log(userPlaylist)
}
``` so I can try to help as it seems you are making a bit of confusion between objects and arrays

Answer (score 0):

Since this.state.playLists is an array you cannot get name on it. you have to get the name of all elements in an array.

Try this in place of console.log(this.state.playLists.name);

```
this.state.platLists.map(playList => console.log(playList.name));
```